# Library for client-side package management

Tags: node.js, cordova, bower, package-managers

I'm trying to build a phonegap app using jquery mobile, backbone and require.js. There are no server-side components. To install and manage the packages, do I need to use node.js or just bower.js is fine? Is there any other tools/libraries available.

Comment: https://github.com/shama/napa

Comment: Bower would probably be sufficient to manage those things, or you could just check them into version control.